# How to give the text gradient color using HTML/CSS in android

Tags: javascript, android, css, gradient

I tried the possible results for giving the text gradient color in android. I used the below javascript to for the text to display gradient color . But, it doesn't support in android. Do anyone have a solution to provide the gradient color to the text using HTML/CSS and supported in android?

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="400"></canvas>     

<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "36px sans-serif";
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 150, 100);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 255, 0)");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText("Gradient Text", 10, 100);  
</script>
```

Thanks for the valuable responses. But to make clear to the question asked, I have

```
<span style='font-family:  MalgunGothic; font-size:10 ;' >Gradient Text</span>
```

For the above html content, gradient color to the text "Gradeient Text" has to be added. If anyone has the solution, please let me know.

Comment: check this article http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/07/24/pure-css-text-gradient-no-pngs/, it could get you idea how to do that, but everything should be checked since webkit in android has some limitations

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `-webkit-gradient` which is all CSS3. Here is a cool [CSS3 gradient generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) that gives you the code with the appropriate colors. Hope this helps.

Comment: to do gradient you need `-webkit-gradient` and `-webkit-mask-image`, but `webkit` in android doesn't support it. Probably, it will support soon ...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the valuable responses. But to make clear to the question, I have